# How to cancatenate multiple Character fields in one many2one field?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to concatenate multiple character fields in a single many2one field and access this in other module. How can we do this?

> For example:- I have 5 character fields with different classes in a
>   module and want to concatenate these 5 character fields in a single
>   many2one field. Also I want access this many2one field in another
>   module.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 3):

Use `name_get` function.

**Ex:**

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('name', 'state')
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for move in self:
        if move.state == 'draft':
            name = '* ' + str(move.id)
        else:
            name = move.name
        result.append((move.id, name))
    return result
```

Hope it will help you.